# jQuery call followed by clicking accordion control fires Ms Jscript error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have jquery modal that works perfectly fine.

But after closing this modal and clicking on accordion control(MS ajax) fires

Jscript runtime error

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   Sys.ArgumentTypeException: Object of
>   type
>   'AjaxControlToolkit.AccordionSelectedIndexChangeEventArgs'
>   cannot be converted to type
>   'Sys.CancelEventArgs'. Parameter name:
>   instance

I have done days of searching. But I couldn't find a solution to this.
I have tried scriptmode="Release". Single reference call to the jquery file.

I read some parts saying that some it helped some people to turn of smart navigation but I couldn't find how to do so.

If anyone has any idea on this it will be much appreciated.

Please.. Help~!

Comment: Try to run jQuery on compatible mode (and update the MS Ajax lib). http://plugins.jquery.com/content/jquery-compatibility-mode

Comment: Thanks for the comment I will try to update the ajaxtoolkit and let you know.

Comment: I am using the most recent version of ajaxtoolkit for .net v3.5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the problem. One of the controls inside the container(div) which is loaded by jquery was throwing an error. So in this case, the error message did not help much to track that particular control down.
Thanks a lot for your effort guys!.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by putting this

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

at the end of my jquery.js file and referencing all jquery functions with a $j, instead of $

Comment: I actually put this on every single page that loads jquery but I used $jq instead of $j.